# how to hide a field when adding content through node/add for a content type?

Tags: entities, nodes

I have 7 fields in a content type and the last field value, I am updating programmatically. So it should not be displayed when adding content to it. What should I do.

Comment: You can use computed field module to add last field.

Comment: will it hides a field??? @Jayendra Kainthola

Comment: Yes, It will hide the field and even you can add token value for calculation in computed field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I prefer is to use [Computed Field](https://drupal.org/project/computed_field) module. Not only it creates a field that's not editable for users, it also takes care about hooks, cache, and lets you simply choose recalculation strategy (on save / on display). All you really need to care with it, is the very code that calculates field's value.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help
[field_hidden](https://drupal.org/project/field_hidden)

Field Hidden defines five hidden field types

text, long text
integer, decimal, floating-point
Hidden in forms
Hidden fields are always rendered as  elements in forms.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go and edit the node content type and in Field Settings change the Field Visibility and Permission. [image]

Just remove the edit permission to any role.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a field in your form programmatically as follows :

```
function hook_form_alter($form,&$form_state, $form_id) {

 if ($form_id == 'your_form_id') {

$field_hidden_value = 'enter your computed value here' ;
   $form['field_hidden'] = array(
      '#type' => 'value',
      '#value' => $field_hidden_value,
   );

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to avoid creating a custom module/using code:

- Install Rules (https://www.drupal.org/project/rules)
- Install Rules Form Support (https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_forms)

Then:

- **Setup a new rule with the event:** Begin [your form name] being built
- **Setup a new action:** Rules Forms > Set an attribute of an element in
  the form
- Set the attribute #access to false

The form element will now be hidden.

If you are trying to avoid creating a custom module, this does the trick.